# What datatype should I use for designing my column to only show date?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm using sql-server 2012 for designing a table and I can't figure out what datatype to use for only accepting a date.

There's datetime and smalldatetime but both include timestamps in them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Date" data type. Eg: CREATE TABLE Table1 ( Column1 date )

Comment: Is there a bug where "date" doesn't appear in design wizard?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho - it wouldn't surprise me. Most of the wizards in management studio are broken in *some* way. Sooner or later you'll have to fix the things they do by going down to the script level and editing the query by hand. So you'll have to get used to what actual queries are being used. After a while, it tends to become more natural to just open a query window and type the query directly, so (in my experience) most experienced developers just don't use the wizards at all.

Comment: Getting this error: "Column, parameter, or variable #8: Cannot find data type date."